# Why can't I get user input when running java using ant?

Tags: java, ant, java.util.scanner

Here is a piece of code to read user input using Scanner.

```
Scanner inner = new Scanner(System.in);
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("Test");
logger.info("Before");
int a = inner.nextInt();
logger.info("After");
......
```

When I use ant to run a java task and excute my code(with "fork=true"), the program get stuck after printing "Before". I can input anything but the "After" never get printed.

However, when using command line java:

```
java -cp build/BoxBugRunner.jar:lib/gridworld.jar com.perqin.boxbugrunner.BoxBugRunner
```

the input is accepted and everything works fine.

It seems that System input cannot be access when using ant to run java program, so how to solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you want to use System.in in an ant build? Ant builds are usually non-interactive.

Comment: @JFMeier Yet I am a newbie to ant...Then how can I interactive with my program(that is, input in terminal and get output) when using ant?

Comment: Ant is usually used as a build tool, i.e. to build your jar, documentation etc. You usually don't run programs with ant. Why do you want to interact with a program called by an ant script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using *System.in* you should:

- **Split your program** in the part before and after the input. In the build script execute the first part, then **get the input via the [Ant input task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/input.html)**, and finally execute the second part with the entered parameters.
- Or write your your **program as Ant task** that delegates to the Ant input task for prompting for input.